# Implement Spring Security for Rest Api

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I use this code for Rest API authentication:

```
@Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
            throws Exception {
        Optional<String> basicToken = Optional.ofNullable(request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION))
                .filter(v -> v.startsWith("Basic"))
                .map(v -> v.split("\\s+")).filter(a -> a.length == 2).map(a -> a[1]);
        if (!basicToken.isPresent()) {
            return sendAuthError(response);
        }

        byte[] bytes = Base64Utils.decodeFromString(basicToken.get());
        String namePassword = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        int i = namePassword.indexOf(':');
        if (i < 0) {
            return sendAuthError(response);
        }
        String name = namePassword.substring(0, i);
        String password = namePassword.substring(i + 1);
//        Optional<String> clientId = authenticationService.authenticate(name, password, request.getRemoteAddr());
        Merchants merchant = authenticationService.authenticateMerchant(name, password, request.getRemoteAddr());
        if (merchant == null) {
            return sendAuthError(response);
        }
        request.setAttribute(CURRENT_CLIENT_ID_ATTRIBUTE, merchant.getId());
        return true;
    }
```

How I can rewrite the code with Spring Security in order to get the same result but for different links to have authentication? For example:

```
localhost:8080/v1/notification - requests should NOT be authenticated.
localhost:8080/v1/request - requests should be authenticated.
```

Comment: Well you are uing a basic authentication so you may use something similar to https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-basic-authentication. In any case for REST API I strongly suggest to you to use OAuth2 and JWT

Comment: @AngeloImmediata can you paste official answer with working code, please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you can find a working project https://github.com/angeloimm/springbasicauth

I know in the pom.xml file there are a lot of useless dependencies but I started from an already existing project and I had no time to depure it

Basically you must:

- configure spring security
- configure spring mvc
- implements your own authentication provider according to spring security. Note I used an inMemoryAuthentication. Please modify it according to yuor own wishes

Let me explain the code.

**Spring MVC Configuration**:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages= {"it.olegna.test.basic"})
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(final List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
    }
}
```

Here we don't do anything else that configuring spring MVC by telling it where to find controllers and so on and to use a single message converter; the `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` in order to produce JSON responses

**Spring Security Configuration**:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Import(value= {WebMvcConfig.class})
public class WebSecConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
     @Autowired private RestAuthEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

        @Autowired
        public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth
              .inMemoryAuthentication()
              .withUser("test")
              .password(passwordEncoder().encode("testpwd"))
              .authorities("ROLE_USER");
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
              .authorizeRequests()
              .antMatchers("/securityNone")
              .permitAll()
              .anyRequest()
              .authenticated()
              .and()
              .httpBasic()
              .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint);
        }
        @Bean
        public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
            return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
        }
}
```

Here we configure Spring Security in order to use HTTP Basic Authentication for all requests except the ones starting with securityNone. We use a `NoOpPasswordEncoder` in order to encode the provided password; this PasswrodEncoder does absolutly nothing... it leaves the passwrod as it is.

**RestEntryPoint**:

```
@Component
public class RestAuthEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,  AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Unauthorized");
    }
}
```

This entrypoint disables all requests not containg the **Authentication** header

**SimpleDto**: a very simple DTO representing the JSON answer form a controller

```
public class SimpleDto implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1616554176392794288L;
    private String simpleDtoName;

    public SimpleDto() {
        super();
    }
    public SimpleDto(String simpleDtoName) {
        super();
        this.simpleDtoName = simpleDtoName;
    }
    public String getSimpleDtoName() {
        return simpleDtoName;
    }
    public void setSimpleDtoName(String simpleDtoName) {
        this.simpleDtoName = simpleDtoName;
    }

}
```

**TestBasicController**: a very simple controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value= {"/rest"})
public class TestBasicController {
    @RequestMapping(value= {"/simple"}, method= {RequestMethod.GET}, produces= {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE})
    public ResponseEntity<List<SimpleDto>> getSimpleAnswer()
    {
        List<SimpleDto> payload = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i= 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            payload.add(new SimpleDto(UUID.randomUUID().toString()));
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(payload);
    }
}
```

So if you try this project by using postman or any other tester you can have 2 scenarios:

- authentication required
- all ok

Let's suppose you want to invoke the URL http://localhost:8080/test_basic/rest/simple without passing the Authentication header. The HTTP Status code will be `401 Unauthorized`

This means that the Authentication Header is required

By adding this header to the request `Authorization Basic dGVzdDp0ZXN0cHdk` all works pretty good
Note that the String `dGVzdDp0ZXN0cHdk` is the Base64 encoding of the string `username:password`; in our case is the Base64 encoding of `test:testpwd` defined in the inMemoryAuthentication

I hope this is usefull

Angelo

**WEB SECURITY USER DATAIL SERVICE**

In order to configure Spring security to retrieve user details from DB you must do the following:

create a org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService implementation like this:

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    private BasicService svc;
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        BasicUser result = svc.findByUsername(username);
        if( result == null )
        {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("No user found with username "+username);
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

Inject it to the spring security configuration and use it like this:

```
public class WebSecConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired private RestAuthEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;
    @Autowired
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
//      auth
//      .inMemoryAuthentication()
//      .withUser("test")
//      .password(passwordEncoder().encode("testpwd"))
//      .authorities("ROLE_USER");
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }
    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authenticationProvider;
    }
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/securityNone")
        .permitAll()
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .httpBasic()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint);
    }
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }
}
```

I pushed the code on the github link I provided. There you can find a full working example based on:

- spring 5
- spring security 5
- hibernate
- h2 DB

Feel free to adapt it to your own scenario

Comment: One more question. Correct me if I'm wrong: I see that user credentials are set during app startup. How I can add methods for DB query for every request?

Comment: I told you I’m using inmemory authentication. You should change it by creating your own detail service

Comment: It turns out that for some links I don't need to use authentication. Please check the updated post.

Comment: Well in this case you must properly configure spring security. Give a look to my configuration. I configure it in order that all requests with path `securityNone` are not protected and so require no authentication. All other requests must have authentication. You should change this configuration according to your own scenario

Comment: One last request. Can you modify the code to use service for database authentication, please?

Comment: OK... but please give me 1 hour.. I have to finish some activity here :)

Comment: I edited the answer. See the **WEB SECURITY USER DATAIL SERVICE** section

Comment: Thanks I will test it later today.

Comment: I tried to implement the code but I found a little problem here auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService); I don't have only username. I have username and password. I need to authenticate both which hare send as `Authorization: Basic OWEwYmJjNDU5ZGZmYTcwY2FhY2JkYmU5YzIzOWMyZmUxNmY4ZjU2MjozRElwZnBMbGZhcW9NVnNSck0yZWFqY3pLUVBSeWwwRFZabDE1UTR1` into http header. Is there a way to implement other way database authentication?

Comment: This is done automatically by spring security by using the password encoder (this is the reason we use it) try to use a wrong password ... it should return error

Comment: And one more issue. I store username and password in entirely different Entity model. Probably I have to return in my query only username and password? Not entire object?

Comment: This is not an issue. Of course I created a very simple sample. Now you have to adapt it to your own scenario. This means: configure spring security and urls properly. Change the sample query to the real query and so on.

Comment: I will try to implement it. Thanks!

Comment: One more question: IN which file I have to configure links which don't require authentication?

Comment: In the class `WebSecConfig` in method `protected void configure(HttpSecurity http)`. Here I configured a non protected access to the URL `/securityNone` because I used `permittAll()`; all others URL are protected because I used `.anyRequest().authenticated()`. You should change `/securityNone` with oyur unprotected URL (e.g. `/public/*`)

Comment: I need to ask a question. How I can configure Spring Security NOT to set role for the user and use password in authentication. Ref https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52225299/configure-spring-to-use-database-for-authentication

Comment: Well its not good thing to not use roles. I strongly suggest to you to re-design your scenarios in using roles. In any case Spring security UserDetails needs at least a role. So you can create a "fake" role never used in your application. Regarding to the password issue... as I told you it's not an issue. After the loading of userdetail spring Security checks the password by using the PasswordEncoder. What I suggest to you is to read deeply the PasswordEncoder section (https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.7.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#core-services-password-encoding)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a default spring-security configuration described on various websites, like [baeldung.com](http://baeldung.com) or [mkyong.com](https://www.mkyong.com/). The trick in your sample seems to be the call to get the `Merchant`. Depending on the complexity of the `authenticationService` and the `Merchant` object, you can either use the following code, or implement a facade to get similar behaviour.

```
@Autowired
public void authenticationManager(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
    auth.authenticationProvider(new AuthenticationProvider() {
        @Override
        public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
            Merchants merchant = authenticationService.authenticateMerchant(name, password, request.getRemoteAddr());
            if(merchant == null) {
                throw new AuthenticationException("No Merchant found.");
            }
            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(name, password, merchant.getAuthorities());
        }

        @Override
        public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
            return (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication));
        }
    });
}
```

Setting the attribute on the request, if necessary could be done by a separate filter which takes the `Principal` from the `SecurityContext` and puts it on the request as an attribute.

Comment: It turns out that for some links I don't need to use authentication. Please check the updated post